# WooCommerce Product Category Description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I don't get it!!! I have managed to include the product category description in their respective pages. I have 6 categories which with four of them I need to add a description. From the four, three worked as it should. However, there is one of them that not only shows its description but also another category's.

[image: Categories]

There are two of each category for multiligual purpose. But you can see the four categories I need to add the description.

1 - Tops
2 - Bottoms
3 - One Pieces
4 - Sport Wear

The first three worked as it should. Ie. Bottoms category page.

[image]

But the fourth, Sport Wear keeps showing not only its description but also the Top category's as well.

[image]

I have already recreated the category Sport Wear, but it remained the same way. I have no clue why this is happening. Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Here is the link: https://morenabeachwear.com/en/product-category/sport-wear/

And here the code I used to loop and display description.

```
function action_woocommerce_archive_description( ) { 

global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat');
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);

foreach ($terms as $term) {

    if (is_product_category()) {

        echo $term->description;

    }
   }
 }; 
  add_action( 'walker_edge_after_page_title','action_woocommerce_archive_description', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with it, but do you need to have the $args in `wp_get_post_terms()`?

Comment: @git-e-up How would you get the description otherwise?

Comment: $terms should still work without the 3rd parameter in there. You've already established that the taxonomy is product_cat in your second param. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/

Comment: Yep, if no `$args` the default is `all`. So it does work as well.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I didn't need the loop. And made sure to echo the first item of the array returned from `wp_get_post_terms`

```
function action_woocommerce_archive_description( ) { 

global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat');

    if (is_product_category()) {
        echo $terms[0]->description;
    }
}; 

add_action( 'walker_edge_after_page_title', 'action_woocommerce_archive_description', 10, 2 );
```